Interaction between http.setTimeout from ESP8266HTTPClient.h and soft / hardware watchdog
To avoid the ESP8266 watchdog to reset the ESP during longer running a http.GET() I use the following code.
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
HTTPClient http;
http.setTimeout(4500);

Will this adapt the watchdog settings (soft and/or hardware) automatically or is an additional
ESP.wdtEnable(5000);

required? And does this approach even work, since I also found that the hardware watchdog will reset if not fed between 1.5 and 2.5 seconds but conflicting statements if this time can be adapted at all.
